# Context is editable in the console, how do I avoid it?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so I am currently working on a shop application and everything goes as it should, except for my authorization-controlling. I store my users in firebase and retract them from there, the user data is stored in a Context. Everything working so far so good.

The user data in my firebase realtime database looks like this:

```
IUWWrNeBHbRex3nWGCKlf2zsSEi2 <br>
authorization: "standard" <br>
email: "bfbasher@gmail.com"
```

The authorization field though can be altered through the web console. I can replace "standard" with "admin" and I get access to admin pages. My question is how can I prevent this?

Comment: by `webconsole ` do you mean localstorage ?

Comment: The problem is not the web console, it's your Firebase settings. You must change your Firebase settings so that nobody can _pretend_ to be an admin, aside from you.

Comment: Set proper Firebase security rules and implement a route guard that checks the role before loading the view.

Comment: Webconsole = F12 -> Console

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers, appriciate it

Answer (score 0):

If you can access your admin page just by changing your localstorage, the issue is elsewhere. When you're protecting your pages/data you have to do it on the server side because on the browser side everyone has access to the code and everyone can change it.

If you are in SPA (every requests is XHR) mode you have to secure all your API endpoints to check if the user is allowed to get/update the data. You can use the firebase security rules https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#production-ready_rules. The display of admin page will still be accessible if the user change his localstorage because the routing is on front side but there is not security risk because data cannot be retrieved by a standard user (the check is done on the API on server side).

If you are in Server Side Rendering (SSR) mode (next.js by example), this will be pretty much the same, you have to check the user authorization on every requests, but the user will not be access anymore to the display of admin pages because all the process is done on server side where the user cannot play with datas.

All this security process is called RBAC (Role-Based Access Control) and there are plenty of tutos on the web like this one https://www.toptal.com/firebase/role-based-firebase-authentication ! Have fun✌️

Comment: Thanks! Figured it out :)